# How to detect whether a web page is multilingual

Tags: http-headers, detection

Given a URL, I need to detect whether the target is available only in one language, or many languages (just that - true/false, no need to detect which languages). Is there any smarter method than sending two requests with different `Accept-Language` fields?

I've thought on this for quite some time, and searched for any useful info, to no avail. I assume there is no information on language in the URL itself. Perfect solution would use just one HTTP request, as that's what bothers me with the only solution I came up with - multiple HTTP requests. The detection feature is to be used in an AJAX call, so each additional HTTP request is a big hit on performance.

Any additional tips, e.g. how to choose which language to use in `Accept-Language`, are welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify more than one language in `Accept-Language`:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I've thought of that - I could send e.g. `Accept-Language: es, en`, expecting `en` to be more likely to be the language of the page than `es`; then if I get `es` as response, I could assume that `en` is also available. But without two actual responses in different languages I cannot be sure if it wasn't just that `es` was the only language available. Especially since I don't have any information on what languages the page might be in.